# Gtk read current keyboard state

Tags: keyboard, gtk3

Is there a function similar to `glfwGetKey` in GTK-3? That is, given a scancode, is it possible to retrieve its state outside a keyboard event handler (which literally tells you what has changed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. This sounds like something that would be more likely to be part of a game programming toolkit or something similar.